# Unusual version of a binary search algorithm

Tags: dynamic-programming, search-algorithms, binary-search, search

For one dimensional, continuous binary search most effective algorithm would remember boundaries.

For example if boundaries are 0.7 and 0.9, point to check would be 0.8. And if result is 'too small', then boundaries become 0.8 and 0.9, and point to check is 0.85. This algorithm is fast and simple.

But it doesnt do well when point we are looking for can move. If point crosses one of the boundaries, we will never find it.

A version that constantly adapts and does not rely on remembering boundaries goes something like this:

If two previous results are the same, for example 'too small', then make the step that you change the search point x2. And if two last results differ, meaning we just crossed the point of interest, make the step x0.5. Then in both cases multuply the last known point by a step value. This version requires 4 times as many steps, and often doesnt converge at all.

Slight improvement is if in each of the 4 cases add a small random factor between 1.1 and 1.5, to avoid cycles. Then it is just 2 times worse than a binary search with remembering boundaries.

Question: what this algorithm is called?

Bonus question: what the problem that im trying to solve is called? So that i can look for other algorithms like this.

Comment: Not exactly what you have described but you may want to look at [exponential search](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search)

Comment: ["moving target" search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22moving+target%22+search)?